# The probability of the order of three variables when given the individual relationship.

Tags: probability

I have three variables $a_1,a_2,a_3$. Each pair has a preference relationship generated from the probability matrix

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}0.5& 0.5& 0.1\\ 0.5& 0.5& 0.4\\ 0.9&0.6&0.5\end{bmatrix}$$

where $Pr\{a_1>a_2\}=A_{12}=0.5$.

So how do i calculate the probability of the three variables' order? Such as $Pr\{a_1>a_2>a_3\}$.